# Remove and replace characters by regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to write a regex that makes the next things:

1. `_` -> replace it by a space
2. `+` -> remove it if there is not another + after it (i.e. `c++`
   => `c++`. `c+` -> `c`)
3. `'` -> remove it if it's in the start or end of the word (i.e.
   `Alin's` -> `Alin's`. `'Alin's` -> `alin's`)
4. `&`, `-`, `.`, `!` - Don't remove.
5. Another special characters - remove

**I want to do it by passing one time the string**

for example:

```
Input: "abc's, test_s! & c++ c+ 'Dirty's'. and beautiful'..."
Output: "abc's test s! & c++ c Dirty's. and beautiful..."
```

Explanation:

```
char `'` in `abc's,` stays because `3`
char `,` in `abc's,` was removed because `5` 
char `_` in `test_s!` was replaced by space because `1`
char `!` in `test_s!` is not removed because `!`
char `&` is not removed because `4`
char `+` in `c++` is not removed because `2`
char `+` in `c+` was removed because `2`
word: `'Dirty's'.` was replaced to `Dirty's.` because `3` and `4`
char `'` in `beautiful'...` was removed because `3`
char `.` is not removed because of `4`
```

This is my `javascript` code:

```
var str = "abc's test_s c++ c+ 'Dirty's'. and beautiful";
console.log(str);
str = str.replace(/[_]/g, " ");
str = str.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 &-.!]/g, "");
console.log(str);
```

This is my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/alonshmiel/LKjYd/4/

I don't like my code because I'm sure that it's possible to do it by running one time over the string.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: What is your output for  this data `"abc's test_s c++ c+ 'Dirty's'. and beautiful"`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter

Comment: @AhosanKarimAsik, The output is:
"Abc's test s c++ c Dirty's. and beautiful"

Comment: I actually sort of like code that shows what it does. In regexes, it's all too easy to produce an unmaintainable long line of gibberish. A couple separate replaces make it absolutely clear what's going on.

Comment: @Alon Shmiel  check my answer...

Comment: Since you are not clear in the second requirement (remove `+` if there is not another `+` after it) most answers did suggest to use a regex which does exactly this. This will however convert `c++` to `c+` while your example implies that this is not the desired result. Please clarify if you in fact mean 'remove `+` if *it is not following or followed by* another `+`'

Comment: What happens when there are three or more consecutive `+`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
function sanitize(str){

  return str.replace(/(_)|(\'\W|\'$)|(^\'|\W\')|(\+\+)|([a-zA-Z0-9\ \&\-\.\!\'])|(.)/g,function(car,p1,p2,p3,p4,p5,p6){

   if(p1) return " "; 
   if(p2) return sanitize(p2.slice(1));
   if(p3) return sanitize(p3.slice(0,-1)); 
   if(p4) return p4.slice(0,p4.length-p4.length%2); 
   if(p5) return car;
   if(p6) return ""; 
 });
}
document.querySelector('#sanitize').addEventListener('click',function(){
  
  document.querySelector('#output').innerHTML=      
   sanitize(document.querySelector('#inputString').value);
});
```

```css
#inputString{
  width:290px
}
#sanitize{
  background: #009afd;
  border: 1px solid #1777b7;
  border:none;
  color:#fff;
  cursor:pointer;
  height: 1.55em;
}

#output{
  background:#ddd;
  margin-top:5px;
  width:295px;
}
```

```html
<input id="inputString" type="text" value="abc's test_s! & c++ c+ 'Dirty's'. and beau)'(tiful'..."/>
<input id="sanitize" type="button" value="Sanitize it!"" />
<div id="output" ></div>
```

some points:

- one pass constraint is not fully respected, due to the obligation to sanitize the character captured with \W. I do not find any other way.
- about the ++ rule: any sequence of + is reduced by one + if impair.
- apostrophs are only removed if there is a non alphanumeric character next to it. What should you want to do with, for example: "abc'&". "abc&" or "abc'&"? And also for "ab_'s".

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter

Answer (score 2):

Because the replacement you need can be different (nothing or a space), you can't use a fixed string (due to the one-pass constraint). So the only way is to use a dynamic replacement.

**direct approach:**

let's try to find the characters to remove, and to preserve in certain cases the others:

```
var str = "abc's, test_s! & c++ c+ 'Dirty's'. and beautiful'...";

var re = /[^\w\s&.!'+-]+|\B'+|'+\B|(\+{2,})|\+|'*(_)'*/g; 

var result = str.replace(re, function (_, g1, g2) {
    if (g1) return g1;
    return (g2) ? ' ' : ''; });

console.log(result);
```

when an underscore is found, the capture group 2 is defined (`g2` in the callback function) and a space is returned.

Note: in the above example the term "word" is taken in a regex meaning (the character class `\w` so `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` except for the underscore), but if you want to be more rigorous, for example to exclude single quotes near digits, you need to change the pattern a little:

```
var re = /[^\w\s&.!'+-]+|(_)'*|([^a-z])'+|'+(?![a-z])|(\+{2,})|\+|^'+/gi;

var result = str.replace(re, function (_, g1, g2, g3) {
    if (g2) return g2;
    if (g3) return g3;
    return (g1) ? ' ' : ''; });
```

Note about the two patterns:

These two patterns consist in an alternation of 6 or 7 subpatterns that can match about 1 or 2 characters most of the time. Keep in mind that to find a character to remove, these patterns must test the 6 or 7 alternatives before failing for each character that must not be replaced. It's an important cost and most of the time a character doesn't need to be replaced.

There is a way to reduce this cost you can apply here: the first character discrimination

The idea is to avoid as much as possible to test each subpatterns. This can be done here because all subpatterns don't begin with a letter, so you can quickly skip all characters that are a letter without to have to test each subpatterns, if you add a lookahead at the begining. Example for pattern 2:

```
var re = /(?=[^a-z])(?:[^\w\s&.!'+-]+|(_)'*|([^a-z])'+|'+(?![a-z])|(\+{2,})|\+|^'+)/gi;
```

For the first pattern you can skip more characters:

```
var re = /(?=[^a-z0-9\s&.!-])(?:[^\w\s&.!'+-]+|\B'+|'+\B|(\+{2,})|\+|'*(_)'*)/gi;
```

Despite these improvements, these two patterns need a lot of steps for a small string (~400) *(but consider that it's an example string with all the possible cases in it)*.

**a more indirect approach:**

Now let's try an other way that consists to find a character to replace, but this time with all characters before it.

```
var re = /((?:[a-z]+(?:'[a-z]+)*|\+{2,}|[\s&.!-]+)*)(?:(_)|.)?/gi

var result = str.replace(re, function (_, g1, g2) {
    return g1 + ((g2) ? ' ' : '' );
});
```

*(Note that there is no need to prevent a catastrophic backtracking because `(?:a+|b+|c+)*` is followed by an always-true subpattern `(?:d|e)?`. Beside, the whole pattern will never fail whatever the string or the position in it.)*

All characters before the character to replace *(the allowed content)* are captured and returned by the callback function.

This way needs more than 2x less steps to do the same job.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is chaining and alternation operator

```
function customReplace(str){
   return str.replace(/_/g, " ").replace(/^'|'$|[^a-zA-Z0-9 &-.!]|\+(?=[^+])/g,"");
}
```

The regex `/^'|'$|[^a-zA-Z0-9 &-.!]|\+(?=[^+])/g` combines all that is needed to be removed. And we replace all `_` by a space, which we finally return.

`\+(?=[^+])` looks for `+` that is followed by anything except `+`

Also, the ordering of the replace is important.

Comment: This will delete the second `+` in `c++` which does not seem to be wanted by the OP. You might need to include a look-ahead as well to ensure you remove only stand-alone '+'s.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:** by regex `/(?!\b)'|'(?=\B)|^'|'$|[^\w\d\s&-.!]|\+(?=[^+])/gm`

```js
function sanitize(str) {
  var re = /(?!\b)'|'(?=\B)|^'|'$|[^\w\d\s&-.!]|\+(?=[^+])/gm;
  var subst = '';
  var tmp = str.replace(re, subst);  // remove all condition without (_) 
  var result = tmp.replace("_", " ");  // next replace (_) by ( ) space.
  return result;
}

document.querySelector('#sanitize').addEventListener('click', function() {

  document.querySelector('#output').innerHTML =
    sanitize(document.querySelector('#inputString').value);
});
```

```css
#inputString {
  width: 290px
}
#sanitize {
  background: #009afd;
  border: 1px solid #1777b7;
  border: none;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 1.55em;
}
#output {
  background: #eee;
  margin-top: 5px;
  width: 295px;
}
```

```html
<input id="inputString" type="text" value="abc's test_s! & c++ c+ 'Dirty's'. and beau)'(tiful'..." />
<input id="sanitize" type="button" value="Sanitize it!" />
<div id="output"></div>
```