# Javascript regexp performance and caching

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, performance

I was looking for an answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28383091/remove-and-replace-characters-by-regex/28529214#28529214), and I have made some performance tests between the responses like that:

```
console.time("first_test");
for( i=0;i<10000;i++)
    result=function1(str);
console.log(result);
console.timeEnd("first_test");


console.time("second_test");
for( i=0;i<10000;i++)
    result=function2(str);
console.log(result);
console.timeEnd("second_test");

this gives: 
first_test: 232ms
second_test: 21ms

And if I reverse the order of the tests: 
second_test: 128ms
first_test: 102ms
```

The functions are almost the same and the regex too, but even if I change the string passed in argument, the second function is always executed faster than if it was executed on first.

So I was wondering at first how the first function speeds up the second, and also more generaly how the regex was cached.

```
function function1(str){

  return str.replace(/(_)|(\'\W|\'$)|(^\'|\W\')|(\+\+)|([a-zA-Z0-9\ \&\-\.\!\'])|(.)/g,function(car,p1,p2,p3,p4,p5,p6,offset){

   if(p1) return " "; 
   if(p2) return sanitize(p2.slice(1));
   if(p3) return sanitize(p3.slice(0,-1)); 
   if(p4) return p4.slice(0,p4.length-p4.length%2); 
   if(p5) return car;
   if(p6) return ""; 
 });
}

function function2(str){

  return str.replace(/(_)|(\++)|([a-zA-Z0-9\ \&\-\.\!])|(\'\W|\'$)|(^\'|\W\')|(\W)/g,function(car,p1,p2,p3,p4,p5,p6){

   if(p1) return " ";
   if(p2) return p2.slice(0,p2.length-p2.length%2); 
   if(p3) return car; 
   if(p4) return p4.slice(1); 
   if(p5) return p5.slice(0,-1); 
   if(p6) return "";
 });
}
```

Comment: so where are `function1` and `function2` ?!

Comment: I have add the functions

Answer (score -3):

### javascript is synchronous. you should write asyn code to see real result

I have tried giving same function and run twice in different loop and I got different console times for same function. Most of the times first test run is always takes longer. But when you add 3rd loop, sometimes 2nd one goes faster and usually 3rd one is fastest. It must be something to do with browsers capability.

```
function test(){
        console.time("second_test");
        for( i=0;i<10000;i++)
            result=function2("str");
        console.log(result);
        console.timeEnd("second_test");


        function test2() {
            console.time("first_test");
            for (i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
                result = function2("str");
            console.log(result);
            console.timeEnd("first_test");
        }
        return test2()
    }


    test();
```

Comment: That change nothing. Why it should be?